# Any npm package for removing background from an image?

Tags: node.js, image, npm, service, background-image

Is there anyone who knows how to remove background from an image with the help of any package?

I tried with remove.bg package, but it seems like a paid service.

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer, I'm the author of rembg.js.

Yes there is, https://www.rembg.com is the only api that allows free API query.

However this is free up to 60 removals per month, it is still great offer when you compare it to other competitors as they do NOT even allow free background removal through API.
if you look at the pricing it is actually extremally cheap subscription starting from 1$ a month per 100 removals.
you can also get unlimited access.

```
npm i --save @remove-background-ai/rembg.js
```

then create index.mjs:

```
import  { rembg } from '@remove-background-ai/rembg.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

// API_KEY will be loaded from the .env file
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

// log upload and download progress
const onDownloadProgress = console.log;
const onUploadProgress = console.log;

rembg({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    inputImagePath: './input.png',
    onDownloadProgress,
    onUploadProgress
}).then(({ outputImagePath, cleanup }) => {
    console.log('path', outputImagePath);
    // if called, it will cleanup (delete from disk) your removed background image
    // cleanup();
});
```

If you want to show progress bar for upload/download you can create your own onDownloadProgress and onUploadProgress callbacks.
both callback accepts **AxiosProgressEvent** as an event params, in my test i was able to remove background and here is the output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check rembg. Although it works in python
https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg

Comment: this is for python, the OP is asking for JS, see my answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the free faceplusplus.com sdk:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/faceplusplus-sdk

The bHumanBodySegmentAPI function works best for detecting human figures and removing backgrounds. (Free rate-limited API key is required, but it's very generous.)